# How do I fix jinja error when launching Voila?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-lab, voila

I am trying to view my Jupyter Lab graphs in Voila for the first time and when I run Voila from the command prompt `$ voila <filename>`, I get the following Traceback:

```
[Voila] Using C:\Users\B****~1\AppData\Local\Temp to store connection files
[Voila] Storing connection files in C:\Users\B****~1\AppData\Local\Temp\voila_lw8qq_9k.
[Voila] Serving static files from C:\Users\br******\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\voila\static.
[Voila] Voilà is running at:
http://localhost:8866/      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\br******\Anaconda3\Scripts\voila-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\br******\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "C:\Users\br******\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\voila\app.py", line 531, in start
    self.listen()
  File "C:\Users\br******\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\voila\app.py", line 575, in listen
    self.launch_browser()
  File "C:\Users\br******\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\voila\app.py", line 606, in launch_browser
    fh.write(template.render(open_url=url, base_url=url))
  File "C:\Users\br******\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "C:\Users\br******\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "C:\Users\br******\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\br******\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\voila\templates\lab\browser-open.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "page.html" %}
  File "C:\Users\br******\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\voila\templates\lab\page.html", line 1, in top-level template code        
    {%- extends 'voila/templates/base/page.html' -%}
  File "C:\Users\br******\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\voila\templates\base\page.html", line 13, in top-level template code      
    {% block stylesheets %}
  File "C:\Users\br******\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\voila\templates\lab\browser-open.html", line 6, in block "stylesheets"
    {{ super() }}
  File "C:\Users\br******\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\voila\templates\lab\page.html", line 11, in block "stylesheets"       
    {{ include_css("static/index.css") }}
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'include_css' is undefined
```

I installed voila 0.2.16 via conda (had issues with mamba) and am using Python 3.9.7 on a Windows computer.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem. Conda was automatically installing an old version of Voila which was incompatible with my version of either Python or Jupyter. Installing via pip loaded the latest version 0.3.2 and it is working now.